# Magic Functions causing error

Tags: php, magic-methods

I've implemented the magic functions `__get()` and `__set()`:

```
function __get($property) {
        if(isset($this->$property)) {
            return $this->$property;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    function __set($property, $value) {
        $this->$property = $value;
    }
```

The following code works fine:

```
$connect->Hammer = "DoubleClawed";
echo $connect->Hammer;
```

However, when I run some of my unit tests, the line:

```
$this->Id = (int) $configXML->ConfigurationFindResults->Configuration->Id;
```

Gives me:

> Trying to get property of non-object

There are other magically set variables before that that work.  I've also tested this code using non-magic methods and it works.  Why does this line set it off?  (`$configXML` is a SimpleXML object)

Comment: Are you sure each of the elements in this chain is an object (eg:  `$configXML`,  `$configXML->ConfigurationFindResults`, `$configXML->ConfigurationFindResults->Configuration`, etc.)? It would be helpful to see some of the code preceding the error, too.

Comment: Are you sure the integer cast isn't running immediately? That would make it a non-object.

Comment: And aren't your magic functions at least a little redundant? PHP already behaves this way without them (returns null on an un-set property), eg: http://codepad.org/7tS7CfFG

Comment: @NullUserException Are you suggesting that he runs his code with error reporting turned off =/?  It's not legit practice to attempt to access an undefined property unless you've defined that it's the actual behavior that you want.

Comment: @TheZ Casting would take place after everything else.

Comment: @Anther It's just a notice. As long as I'm aware of what's being done, I don't care. All error reporting gets shut down in production anyways.

Comment: @NullUserException I haven't worked much in php, but in the operator precedence chart it's pretty far up there (3rd from the top). Are you sure this it'll run afterwards? I'd test it but I'm not at home right now. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: @NullUserException Working with a team.. things get so nasty if you're playing around with undeclared variable references. Bugs go unnoticed from misnamed variable references returning null silently, and no one codes perfectly, especially if you disable your debugging tools. And if you ever inherit codebases you really appreciate the ones that stick to the it, as ones without it tend to be literally littered with so many notices that you can't even properly debug the code.  I do not see what's to be gained by coding lazily against the language's conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your magic `__get` and  `__set` look fine to me. (I use the same code in my app).

Your error comes form  `$configXML->ConfigurationFindResults->Configuration->Id;`

Comment: If I may ask, why are you using that same code in your app? It works the same way without it: http://codepad.org/7tS7CfFG

Comment: @JdvBerg Why would you make it private in the first place if you know you'll violate private access? (this isn't rhetorical, I'm genuinely interested in knowing what are use cases for this)

Comment: But then you wouldn't be using *that same code*, right? I'm not saying using `__set()` and `__get()` is not useful, just that I don't see the difference in this particular case.

Comment: For readonly you could use the get only, for lazy loading you have to translate the get in a getter function